# Error when initializing mapper mapped SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table who has a reference to 2 other tables in a relation One to Many.

I've tried a lot things but i can't find a similar example of what I want to do. Bellow there is code and description when occurs the error.

Conversas.py:

```
from .model import db
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON

class Conversa(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "conversas"
    id = db.Column('ConversaId',db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fkEmpresa = db.Column('FkEmpresa', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('empresas.empresaId'),nullable=False)
    fkTipoUsuario = db.Column('FKTipoUsuario', db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('tiposUsuarios.tipoUsuarioId'),nullable=False)
    # other fields
```

Empresas.py:
from .model import db

```
class Empresa(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "empresas"
    id = db.Column('empresaId',db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    #some fields
    empresaCaracteristicas = db.relationship('EmpresaCaracteristica', backref='empresas', lazy=True)
    conversas = db.relationship('Conversa', backref='empresas', lazy=True)
```

TipoUsuario.py:

```
class TipoUsuario(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tiposUsuarios"
    id = db.Column('tipoUsuarioId',db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    #some fields
    usuarios = db.relationship('Usuario', backref='tiposUsuarios', lazy=True)
    conversas = db.relationship('Conversa', backref='tiposUsuarios', lazy=True)
```

I've tried to insert some values and this error occurs:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped failed to locate a name ("name '' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'banco_nestorgr.tabelas.tipoUsuarioModel.TipoUsuario'> class after both dependent classes have been defined
```

Answer (score 0):

The backref in class TipoUsuario(db.Model): shouldn't be the same

try to rename backref